# Using .htaccess to redirect obsolete browsers

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, browser, obsolete

Im trying to redirect few browsers using htaccess to a page that would suggest to update their browser and I cant figure it out with the .htaccess file:

Currently I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 6"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ie/
```

but that transfers only internet explorer 6. How can I add more browsers and where can I find their user_agent names? I found this article online: http://evansims.com/6032/using-htaccess-to-redirect-obsolete-browsers/ which suggests this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Opera/3" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Opera/2" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Opera/1" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Safari/4" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Safari/3" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Safari/2" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Safari/1" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Navigator/" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 6" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 5" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 4" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 3" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 2" [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 1"
RewriteRule . upgrade.html [L]
```

but it doesn't seem to work for me. Is there any website that provides a list with the http user agents in bulk? For example when I say Firefox 3.0 it means all versions including 3.6

This website: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/ has hundreds of user agents which Im pretty sure there is a way to include all of them in one row? ( Like IE6,7 Firefox 1 to 3 (including 3.6), Opera 1 to 10 etc )

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera/[1-3] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari/[1-4] [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Navigator/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE [1-6]
RewriteRule .? upgrade.html [L]
```

This should work better.

Answer (score 1):

@ Jeff

You can't use [1-15] because that says 1 thru 1 or 5

You need to use something like [1-9] which means 1 thru 9. You can can't use double digits in a range like that.

So you would have to do it like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox/[1-9][0-5]?\. [NC,OR]
```

[1-9][0-5]?

Means 1 thru 9, with or without a 0 thru 5

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Mobile or desktop browser detection and redirect to respective web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660649/mobile-or-desktop-browser-detection-and-redirect-to-respective-web-page)

Can you do it with php or other backend instead? The following is for mobile detection, but you could easily put in your own user agent list. If the condition is met

```
 <?php
 $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
 // insert php redirect code here
 ?>
```