# How to build a mobile version of a non-mobile website?

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, mobile

We have a website and we now would like to make a mobile version of it. We would like for it to be as easy as possible, like just build an entirely new HTML and CSS site with some of the content from the original. We would like to build it in its own "m" subdirectory.

Is it as easy as just building the site, sticking it in the subdirectory and redirecting the site to mobile devices? How would I go about doing that, though JAVA (which we would like to stay away from), code in the HEAD or editing the .htaccess file?

This is our first time trying the mobile route, so I am pretty ignorant to the process.

Comment: How am I getting down-voted for a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile WAP sites need to be coded in xHTML MP (Mobile profile) markup as this is most friendly for mobile devices CSS need to use ,,em" value for sizes instead of,, pxl" because it's not good to use absolute values in CSS for mobile site .You can use auto index page to recognize type of browsers or OS and to redirect on WEB or WAP version of your site

Comment: Thank you for your response. I cannot upvote you because I don't have enough reputation. How would I go about using auto index page?

Comment: Here is some example with redirect and detection view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660649/mobile-or-desktop-browser-detection-and-redirect-to-respective-web-page

Comment: Here is my mobile site: http://www.m.rentalcarmomma.com/test.htm - I cannot get the text on the bottom to scale properly with the rest of the site. Any suggestions?