# How to automatically Request Desktop Site For Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a wordpress site with a responsive theme. My only problem is that music players don't work on mobile devices because it needs the user to first check "Request desktop site" on the browser settings. If i do check request desktop site on the settings, the format is still the responsive one, but the players work (Music can finally be played).

Is there any way i could set up my wordpress site(plugins, or configurations) such that the desktop version is automatically requested?

I wouldn't want my visitors to do other stuff before exploring the site. They might even go away before trying out the "Request desktop site" option.

Here's the theme i use : http://themeforest.net/item/remix-musicbandclubpartyevent-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/8473753

And my plugin for the music player : https://wordpress.org/plugins/grand-media/

Comment: You can't force a users browser to do something _they might not want it to do_, just because _you_ want it to. If you don't want your site to be responsive, disable all the responsive code (which may include CSS media queries, and possibly some javascript functions depending on the theme).

Comment: You can try the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660649/mobile-or-desktop-browser-detection-and-redirect-to-respective-web-page